# onBackPressed() shows error

Tags: android, android-activity, popup

I want to add an exit warning when click on the back button from mainactivity. For that i am using this code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final Dialog dialoge=new Dialog(MainActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialoge.setContentView(R.layout.popup_layout);

    Button yes=(Button)dialoge.findViewById(R.id.yes);
    yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            MainActivity.this.finish();

        }
    });
    Button no=(Button)dialoge.findViewById(R.id.no);
    no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialoge.cancel();
        }
    });


    dialoge.show();
}
```

and this is working, but shows some error when exiting.

The Logcat is

```
  03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488): Activity com.example.design.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@447fec28 that was originally added here
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.design.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@447fec28 that was originally added here
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:251)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at com.example.design.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:97)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:1895)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1283)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2075)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1673)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2493)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2463)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1752)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-21 10:25:57.192: E/WindowManager(14488):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why do you want to show a dialog if the app would close anyway?

Comment: I want to make sure that, the user really want to exit, not press the back key accidentally.

Comment: exit means quit from the application

Comment: @AlexChengalan, it's bad UX to implement an Exit dialog for apps. A lot of apps do it, but they shouldn't be, Every Android user know that pressing back will close the application, asking him to press another button just to confirm it will irritate. Better not to have the exit dialog at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not dismissing the dialog thats what warning says its leaking.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // here you need to dismiss your dialog before finishing activity
        if (dialoge != null) {
            dialoge.cancel();
            dialoge = null;
        }

        MainActivity.this.finish();

    }
```

Comment: Make sure you check for `dialoge` being null!

Answer (score 2):

You can give it a try just call yes button like this:

```
Button yes=(Button)dialoge.findViewById(R.id.yes);
    yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialoge.cancel();
            MainActivity.this.finish();

        }
    });
```

Dialog needs to be cancelled before exiting the application. That's why it is showing the `leaked window error`  as the dialog is open.

Answer (score 1):

Dismiss Dialog too, call `dailog.dismiss()` or `dialog.cancel()` after finishing activity, I tested your code, and its should look like below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    final Dialog dialoge=new Dialog(SecondActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialoge.setContentView(R.layout.popup_layout);

    Button yes=(Button)dialoge.findViewById(R.id.yes);
    yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            finish();
            dialoge.cancel();

        }
    });
    Button no=(Button)dialoge.findViewById(R.id.no);
    no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            dialoge.dismiss();
        }
    });


    dialoge.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dialoge.dismiss();
```

implement in your onClick method of yes Button